# Validate spreadsheet data against [Reply-To] value in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently, I have to manually vet my sales spreadsheet with confirmed payment through interac e-transfer against the emails I receive. I'm trying to see if it's possible to write an app script that checks the (ReplyTo) field of an email against the email column in a spreadsheet. If the values match, And a Yes/No value in a new column of that row. Is this possible?

My initial thought was this would need to run as a loop for every email inside of a label. Once it has been added then label would be removed so that the script doesn't take forever to run against old emails.

The expected result would be to have a spreadsheet over approxiately 300 orders have a column called "Paid" with either yes/no as values in each row and then I can use that to follow-up on orders.

Comment: Looks like an interesting task to work on :) What have you tried so far? Feel free to share some code with any confidential details redacted from it so folks from SO community could build from thereon forward.